# Visual Studio shows "Select a smart card device" window when attempting to run WebAPI

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-webapi, smartcard

I have a WebAPI project that I'm trying to debug. When I attempt te run it from Visual Studio, a Windows Security window pops up telling me to select a smart card device.

[image]

When I close this window twice, the following error pops up:

[image]

The project has nothing to do with smartcards, and runs without a problem on other computers.

I've attempted to fix this by disabling all smartcard related services, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

In the IIS SSL configuration for the site, I've set Client certificates to "Ignore" instead of "Accept". It's not a perfect solution, but at least I can debug the code now.